# Docker w/ docker-compose and dockerfile laravel error

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I have looked through multiple questions on here and have not been able to find a solution to my answer.

I have a docker compose file as the following:

```
    version: "3.8"
services:
    oauth_database_container:
        image: mysql:5.7.30
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - mysql.env
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes: 
            - oauth_database_data_container:/var/lib/mysql
    oauth_php_container:
        image: php:7.3-fpm
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        depends_on: 
            - oauth_database_container
    oauth_nginx_container:
        image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on: 
            - oauth_database_container
            - oauth_php_container
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./docker/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
volumes:
    oauth_database_data_container:
    oauth_php_data_container:
```

I think have my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libldap2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev git && \
    docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
RUN docker-php-ext-install ldap mysqli curl json xml pdo_mysql zip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
```

When I go into the container and run compose install this is the error I am getting.

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'oauth.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)

  at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider))
      [internal]:0

  2   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'oauth.permissions' doesn't exist")
      /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:63

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

What can I do to fix this issue? I have looking into running the php artisan migrate commands but I cannot till the composer autoload file is there. So I'm a bit of a pickle.

Comment: I was going to say try running composer install with `--no-scripts` so you can get past that error, but you have it commented out in your Dockerfile?

Comment: I had it in there and it still fails. The compose install works but then I cannot do anything until I do php artisan migrate but that needs the autoload which doesnt get added with the --no-scripts.

Comment: I am assuming one of two things. 1) The container for my mysql is not open to that container for some reason or another. I can connect to the mysql via DBeaver on my host however. 2)  My Dockerfile is for some reason not in the right context. I noticed on up if those commands are not comments out it will not run them saying that compose down not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, and I've resolved it by using two commands from Composer

```
composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
```

This is exactly what you have commented in your Dockerfile. When everything is installed, I ran following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And everything works well again.

Comment: So I tried that and the first script works, however the second fails with the same error.

Comment: You get the same error because you have to add "artisan migrate" command after  "composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader" and before "composer dump-autoload". The reason is simple, "Table 'oauth.permissions' doesn't exist" when you are trying to run composer install with  "postAutoloadDump" action